# How can I access my ViewModel from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I don't understand how I can create a command to create a MVVM clickable rectangle. Here is my code:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Color01" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" MouseDown="Color_MouseDown" />
<Rectangle x:Name="Color02" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="115,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="Color03" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="220,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="Color04" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="325,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

On my first rectangle you can see I created a code behind event. First I don't know how to access my ViewModel from the code behind. Two it's not really MVVM.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
    }

    private void Color_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // So what ???
    }
}
```

I just need to be able to change a simple boolean value stored in a list stored in my viewModel when someone click on my rectangle. Why it is so complicate to do with MVVM?

Comment: `var rect = sender as Rectangle` and then do whatever you want to it, although this is very bad design and you _should_ by all means use data binding and bind the color to a field rather than doing this. Learn and utilize the abstractions you are given rather than fight them.

Comment: And i get the rectangle... then what next? Getting the sender is not the problem. After that I need to update my boolean value stored in a list stored in my viewModel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't too difficult. First, create an instance of your ViewModel inside your Window XAML:

**View XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="BuildAssistantUI.BuildAssistantWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:MySolutiom.ViewModels">
     <Window.DataContext>
         <VM:MainViewModel />
     </Window.DataContext>
  </Window>
```

After that, you can [`System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.invokecommandaction(v=expression.40).aspx) to translate your event to a command:

**View XAML:**

```
<Grid>
 <Rectangle x:Name="Color01" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" MouseDown="Color_MouseDown">
   <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
      <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
          <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
      </interactivity:EventTrigger>
   </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Now, in your ViewModel, set up an [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx) implementation to bind to that event:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnRectangleClicked);
    }

    public void OnRectangleClicked()
    {
        // Change boolean here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39):

In MVVM you shouldn't be accessing your view model from code behind, the view model and view are ignorant of each other a here endeth the lecture :)

Instead you can attach the EventToCommand behaviour to your control. This lets you bind an event in the control to a command in the data context. See [msdn commands tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) here.

If you are desperate to do it, you can access the controls data context property and cast it to your view model type to give access to the internals.

```
var vm = (ViewModelType)this.DataContext;
vm.CommandProperty.Execute(null);
```

Comment: Hi kidshaw, do you have any good resources for keeping the ViewModel and code-behind separate? I am working on a code-behind now which is coupled to the ViewModel via a property. I know this isn't ideal but it feels unavoidable for the execution order of ViewModel.Method, View.Method, ViewModel.Method that I need.

Comment: @Chucky - simply because that is the MVVM pattern. If you introduce code behind it should only supplement the view and not access the view model. It may not be worth it for your application, but you can normally find a way to keep the pattern using DataTriggers, EventToCommand and maybe a custom behaviour. If that interests you, post your problem.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. Since you set `DataContext` property to point to your ViewModel within View, they are bound. Moreover, all the `Binding`-s are again aware of the properties defined in ViewModel. So View always aware of ViewModel. However the opposite is not correct: ViewModel should never be bound to View.

Answer (score 19):

Quick answer. This might help others as well

```
((MyViewModel)(this.DataContext)).MyProperty
```

Comment: Changing `DataContext` to `BindingContext` works for me.

Answer (score 7):

**In a C# XAML UWP MVVM Context.**

Consider the following example

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FrostyTheSnowman.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }        

        public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using FrostyTheSnowman.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FrostyTheSnowman
{
    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public User user { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            user = new User
            {
                FirstName = "Frosty",
                LastName = "The Snowman"                
            };
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<Page
    x:Class="FrostyTheSnowman.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FrostyTheSnowman"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Name="sp1" DataContext="{Binding user}">

            <TextBox Name="txtFirstName"                     
                 Header="First Name"
                 Text="{Binding FirstName}" />

            <TextBox Name="txtLastName"                     
                 Header="Last Name"
                 Text="{Binding LastName}" />


        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

code-behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace FrostyTheSnowman
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        MainPageViewModel vm;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize the View Model Object
            vm = (MainPageViewModel)this.DataContext;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vm.user.ToString() + " was a jolly happy soul");
        }
    }
}
```

When u run the app you'll see:

[image]

But more importantly,  the debug trace will show:

[image]

It shows that the code-behind has indeed successfully accessed the ViewModel...

Hope this helps

Comment: And now I have "Frosty The Snowman" song stuck in my head. Great.